# Determine if all elements of a list belong to the same DU case

Tags: f#

I have a discriminated union with 10-15 cases, all having data in the form of `int<'a>`:

```
type MyUnionType =
    | Case1 of int<someUnit>
    | Case2 of int<someUnit>
    | 
    ...
    | CaseN of int<someOtherUnit>
```

I am new to functional programming and am struggling to write a function with the following signature:

```
mySum:MyUnionType option list -> MyUnionType option
```

The function should sum all the ints **iff all the `Some` elements belong to the same DU case**. For example:

```
mySum [Some (Case1 2<a>), Some (Case1 3<a>), None] = Some Case1 5<a>
mySum [Some (Case1 2<a>), Some (Case2 3<a>), None] = None
mySum [None] = None
```

I know about `Option.map` and `List.choose` and the likes that can help here, but I'm struggling with determining whether all elements belong to the same case.

Is there an elegant and FP-idiomatic way to write this function? (If it simplifies matters, you can assume the list is never empty.)

(Though I don't have a clear grasp on monoids/monads/morphisms yet, don't be afraid to use the words if relevant, though please stop a bit short of zygohistomorphic prepromorphisms).

Comment: Haha, did you come upon this problem naturally? It looks pretty straightforward, but has quite a few intricacies, particularly if you want to come up with a "pretty" solution. Would make a good interview question.

Comment: @scrwtp I'm making a cooking calculator for Zelda: Breath of the Wild as an excercise for myself. Ingredients may or may not have effects, and effects are associated with a kind of numerical potency (hearts restored, potency points for some other effects, etc.) You only get an effect from cooking ingredients together if you only have one effect across all of them (multiple effects = no effect in the cooking result), and the total potency is the sum of the potency of all the ingredients with that effect.

Comment: You'd have easier time by using a tuple/record of (effect type, potency) to model that. This would let you group by effect type, check how many such groups you have, and sum within groups. DUs where all the cases take the same arguments are usually a code smell - this suggests that the cases were split along a common property, rather than a quality that truly differentiates them.

Comment: @scrwtp But the cases don't take the same arguments - all are different. One takes seconds, another takes number of hearts, and most take some effect-specific potency points. Sure, all are essentially ints in this case, but considering the units, they are different types. Thus I can't use a tuple, since the potency type is different for each effect. (I don't HAVE to do this, but the F# type system encourages encoding these things into the model, and I'm doing this mostly as a type design excercise.)

Comment: Fair enough - I do agree you're just making things more complicated for yourself that way. Your scenario still feels better represented with an open universe of types, i.e. something that OO part of F# has better answers to than the FP part. I'd look to make concessions, perhaps by making "potency" an abstract measure decoupled from what it represents for a particular effect. But that's outside the scope of the question, so I'll stop at that. Cheers.

Comment: That is in fact exactly what I ended up doing in my latest iteration. It made it easier to reuse the effect types, and also to make the whole effect type monoidal, for easier combination of effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the code I'm about to present you will be greatly simplified if you remove all the `None` cases from the list before summing it. So for the rest of my answer, I'm going to assume that you've run your list through a `List.choose id` step first to get rid of all the `None` values.

The simplest way to think about this is probably to break it down into a series of single steps. You start by taking the first item of the list to initialize your "sum so far" value. (If there was *no* first item after running the list through `List.choose id`, then the list was either empty or contained only `None`s, so the sum in that case will be `None`). Now, if that was the only item of the list, then you've already found the sum of the entire list. Otherwise, you look at the first item of the *rest* of the list, and ask the following question:

1. Is that item the same DU case as the sum so far?

If the answer is yes, then you add its value to the sum so far, and keep going through the loop. If the answer is no, then you make the "sum so far" value a `None` value instead of `Some (case)`. So really, the "is it the same as the sum so far" question is actually two questions:

1. Is the "sum so far" a real value? (I.e., not `None`)?
2. Is the item I'm looking at the same DU case as the sum so far?

If the answer to both of these questions is "yes", then you add up the two values to get a new "sum so far" value. If it's "no", then you just set the "sum so far" to `None`, and your eventual result will be `None` as well.

Translating that approach into code looks like this:

```
let addToSum sumSoFar nextItem =
    match sumSoFar with
    | None -> None  // Short-circuit if we previously found a mismatch
    | Some x ->
        match x, nextItem with
        | Case1 a, Case1 b -> Some (Case1 (a + b))
        | Case2 a, Case2 b -> Some (Case2 (a + b))
        // ...
        | CaseN a, CaseN b -> Some (CaseN (a + b))
        | _ -> None  // Mismatch
```

Now you need a function to apply a "combining" operation like that to the whole list. (A "combining" operation is any operation that takes two items of the same type and produces a single item of that same type; addition is one such operation, but so is multiplication, and a bunch of other things). There are two basic "apply this combining operation to the whole list" functions in F#, [`reduce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.reduce%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) and [`fold`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.fold%5b't,'state%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d). The difference is that `reduce` takes the first item of the list as the initial "sum so far" value, and cannot work on an empty list. Whereas `fold` requires you to supply the initial value of its "sum so far" accumulator, but it *can* work on an empty list (for an empty list, the result of `fold` will simply be the initial "sum so far" value that you provided). In your case, since you don't initially know the type that your "sum so far" value should hold, you have to use `reduce`. So I'd suggest something like this:

```
let sumMyList values =
    values |> List.choose id |> List.reduce addToSum
```

Except that `List.reduce` can't handle an empty list, and if the list you have is entirely `None` cases, that would blow up. (Can you see why?) So I'll add one more step to it, to handle empty lists:

```
let reduceSafely filteredValues =
    match filteredValues with
    | [] -> None
    | _  -> filteredValues |> List.reduce addToSum

let sumMyList values =
    values |> List.choose id |> reduceSafely
```

That should get you what you're looking for. And hopefully it's also given you insight into the process of designing a functional solution to your problems.

P.S. I recommend the F# track at http://exercism.io/ if you want more practice in figuring out the functional approach to problem-solving. I learned a *lot* running through those exercises!

Comment: Thanks! That's a very well-phrased and helpful answer. I get it - make a function that handles two values, and reduce the list using that. I have seen similar approaches other places, too, but I was hoping I could avoid having to spell out all the cases in the sum function, so I hadn't yet started to consider such approaches. Perhaps I can refactor my types to avoid this problem altogether - this deserves more thought either way. I'll definitely check out exercism, thanks!

Comment: There's also a way where you wouldn't have to spell out the cases in the match expression, but it would involve using reflection to get at the case values -- and I prefer to avoid reflection since it's a pretty advanced .Net topic. I like simpler code, even if it means it's a bit longer. Besides, with the Ionide extension to VS Code, it can fill out the `match` expression for you after you've typed just the first case. VERY nice.

Comment: I've never used VS Code, only VS2017. Is the F# experience better in VS Code?

Comment: I haven't used Visual Studio for F# work so I don't have personal experience there. But there have been several F#-related bugs in the VS 2017 release lifecycle. (VS 2015 didn't have this problem, but the VS 2017 release was fumbled a little bit due to everyone's attention being on .NET Core). I know that Ionide can handle one project type (I think it's the newest `.fsproj` type from .NET Core) that VS 2017 can't handle yet, but I don't know the details.